# Error: operator *: nonconformant arguments (op1 is rxc, op2 is rxc )

Tags: matlab, kernel-density, probability-density

I have implemented the following function to estimate [Parzen Density of a matrix](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/146091/3804),

**parzen.m**

```
function [retval] = parzen (matrix, dataPoint, variance)
    [r c] = size(matrix);
    A = ones(r, c)*dataPoint;
    sub = matrix - A;
    up = sub.^2;
    dw = 2 * variance;
    firstPart = 1/(sqrt(2*pi*variance));
    retval = firstPart * exp((-1)*(up/dw));
```

**Error**

```
>> parzen(train, test, 0.25)
error: parzen: operator *: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 1824x8, op2 is 1824x8
)
error: called from
    parzen at line 3 column 4
>>
```

How can I get rid of this error?

Comment: Don't you need to use element-wise multiplication? Assuming `dataPoint` is a matrix of size (r,c) use `A = ones(r,c) .* dataPoint`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The commenet from [@Benoit_11](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3352541/benoit-11) solved my issue.

```
A = ones(r,c) .* dataPoint.
```